# $FA_{\kappa}(\mathbb{P}) \iff BFA_{\kappa}(\mathbb{P})$, if $\mathbb{P}$ is a $\kappa^+$-cc poset.

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

I'm trying to prove the question in the title, where the axioms are enunciated like

> $FA_{\kappa}(\mathbb{P})$ is the assertion that for each colection $\{I_{\alpha} : \alpha < \kappa\}$ of maximal antichains of $\mathbb{P}$, there exists a filter $G\subseteq \mathbb{P}$ such that $I_{\alpha}\cap G \not = \emptyset$, for all $\alpha<\kappa$.

> $BFA_{\kappa}(\mathbb{P})$ is the assertion that for each colection $\{J_{\alpha} : \alpha < \kappa\}$ of maximal antichains of $\ \mathbb{B}=RO(\mathbb{P})\setminus\{0\}$, with each one of size at most $\kappa$, there exists a filter $G\subseteq \mathbb{B}$ such that $J_{\alpha}\cap G \not = \emptyset$, for all $\alpha<\kappa$.

The only trick I'm working one is how to code antichanis and filters of $\mathbb{P}$ into antichains and filters of $\mathbb{B}$ (and vice versa).

My attempt on $\rightarrow$ part was, after assuming $FA_{\kappa}(\mathbb{P})$ and fixing an arbitrary antichain $J_{\alpha}=\{U_{\theta}\in \mathbb{B} : \theta < \kappa\}$  was to just pick one element of each regular open $U_{\theta}$ and produce an antichain of $\mathbb{P}$. But it turns out that the resulting antichain need not to be a maximal one.

My attempt on $\leftarrow$ part was, after assuming $BFA_{\kappa}(\mathbb{P})$ and fixing an arbitrary antichain $I_{\alpha}=\{p_{\theta}\in \mathbb{P} : \theta<\kappa\}$, I set $U_{p_{\theta}}=\{q\in\mathbb{P}: q\leq p_{\theta}\  \mbox{ or } \ p_{\theta}\leq q\} \in \mathbb{B}$. But the colection $J_{\alpha}$ made of these $U_{p_{\theta}}$ need not to be an antichain.

I also tried several other non-successful methods which I can exhibit if you judge useful.

Could you guys help me on this? Do I need to go to Stone Space arguments? To get a better characterization of the regular open sets or something like that...

Comment: I also wrote an attempt on how to get a generic filter $H$ of $\mathbb{B}$ from a generic $G$ of $\mathbb{P}$ and vice versa, tried something like closing upward and downward $G$ to get a regular subset, but this $H$ doesn't seem to intersect each antichain, as we needed

Comment: Note that the map $p\mapsto \mathrm{ro}(p)$ is a complete embedding from $\mathbb{P}$ to $\mathrm{RO}(\mathbb{P})$ where $\mathrm{ro}(p)=\{q:\text{no extension of }q\text{ is compatible with }p\}$.

Comment: @JunderscoreH are you suggesting me to take $U_{p_{\theta}}=ro(p_{\theta})$? But couldn't be the case that $U_{p_{\theta}}\cap U_{p_{\beta}}\not = \emptyset$? And then this doesn't produce an antichain of $\mathbb{B}$?

Comment: If $A$ is a maximal antichain of $\mathbb{P}$, then $\mathrm{ro}{"}A=\{\mathrm{ro}(p):p\in A\}$ is a maximal antichain of $\mathrm{RO}(\mathbb{P})$.  So if you have a collection of maximal antichains of $\mathbb{P}$, you can translate them to $\mathrm{RO}(\mathbb{P})$ and then intersect them with some $G$ assuming $BFA_\kappa(\mathbb{P})$, the pullback of $G$ generates a filter for $\mathbb{P}$ and those antichains.